# cannot run webdriver.Firefox from selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am having trouble using Selenium

I am using Python 3.6, on a Windows 7 machine at my workplace. Firefox is 61.0.1 (64-bit)
Python is loaded in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32`

My work is in `H:\PythonPrograms`

I have successfully installed selenium:
C:\Windows\System32>`pip install selenium`
`Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages (3.13.0)`

Per other advice found here, I downloaded `geckodriver.exe` and placed it both into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32` and `H:\PythonPrograms`.

My path includes: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;H:\PythonPrograms`

I am following the steps on "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" (Al Sweigart) p. 257

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 159, in __init__
    log_path=log_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'


>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'H:\PythonPrograms')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'H:\PythonPrograms')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 159, in __init__
    log_path=log_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
>>>
```

(IT's not the permissaion on geckodriver.log. This even happens when I delete that file and try again. Also I checked permissions: )

When I run Python as administrator from a new Python session:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'H:\PythonPrograms')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'H:\PythonPrograms')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'PythonPrograms' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I don't understand what is happening between me running Python normally vs running as administrator. Whichever, neither way gives me expected output.

---

added new run example by changing the executable_path to include the program name and remove the "r" qualifier. Here are the new results:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='H:\PythonPrograms\geckodriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='H:\PythonPrograms\geckodriver.exe')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expression try to give exact path with exe file name

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='H:\PythonPrograms\yourexenamehere.exe')
```

Comment: I changed the command per your suggestion. It looked like I got further along. This time a command terminal opened for a few moments. This like 'selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities', is it telling me I need to configure something?

Comment: Content of geckodriver.log is ...
`1533753638404 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.21.0 (c7d3022be6420de1ca4076d932aa32b299f3ea10 2018-06-14)
1533753638414 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:52190`

Comment: looks like your ff is 64 bit, are you using correct version 64bit for your geckodriver and also selenium webdriver?

Comment: Noooooo!, I'm running 32 bit geckodriver!!!!! Cuz, python is installed in Program Files (x86), I thought it went along with Python not Firefox!

Was that it all along!

Thank you, @theGuy. I will keep the thread posted.

Comment: No, Gecko Driver is the link between your tests in Selenium and the Firefox. You can find more information on internet. Make sure python, selenium, ff, geckodriver have same 32 or 64 bit.